# A Juju Charm that configure dependencies to work with jenkins

Tags: juju

I'm doing a charm that installs jenkins and stuff. If the User already have an account on github and create a new repository named "builder", he can put the dependencies for the job as app engine, gwt ... and can still put a bash script for installation of other dependencies or even organization of folders. It can also be placed a config.xml file that would create the job in jenkins. So no need to get into the machine to make such configurations.
I wonder if this charm would be useful for the community?
Thanks!

Edit - I already know the jenkins charm, but it just install jenkins and nothing more than that. So our needs were to automatize all the environment configuration without enter in machine to make the enviroment.
Based on charm Jenkins we modified to pull a repository named builder from github and there you can put a  bash script to install dependencies that the charm runs and a config.xml with the jenkins job that will be created.

For our projects this facilitates the jenkins configuration so we can just change few parameters to deploy it. We already try to use this function to install scripts but we had some problems with that and using a repository you are able to change somethings without having to deploy a charm in any alteration.

Comment: Can't you just do the extra things in the Jenkins build script?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a Jenkins charm in the [Juju Charm Store](http://jujucharms.com/charms/precise/jenkins). I'm not sure I completely grasp what you're trying to do though. The README for the charm outlines how to add custom install scripts which I think may be along the lines of what you're referring to.

Comment: And you can specify a list of extra packages required.